# SQL UPDATE with if else conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the columns `post_author` and  `post_user` with variables if the respective columns are not empty in the table. If to take off those particular conditions and leave only one, for example `post_author`, then everything is working, I have problems only with the sql 'case' part.

Having this issue:

> Notice: Fail You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'SET post_author = case when post_author !=null then
>   'evgen' else null end, SET p' at line 1

```
$query = "UPDATE posts SET post_title = '{$post_title}', 
post_tags= '{$post_tags}', 
post_date = now(), 
post_image = '{$post_image}', 
post_content = '{$post_content}',  
post_status = '{$post_status}', 
post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', 
SET post_author = case when post_author !=null then '{$post_author}' 
                                               else null end, 
SET post_user = case when post_user !=null then '{$post_user}' 
                                           else null end 
WHERE post_id = $the_great_post_id ";
```

I have this HTML:

```
<?php  
if(null !=  $post_user) {
?>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_user">User</label>

       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_user" value="<?php echo $post_user; ?>">
    </div>

<?php   }
if(null !=  $post_author) {
?>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_author">Author</label>

       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_author" value="<?php echo $post_author; ?>">
       </div>

<?php   }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `SET` for the last two values

```
  $query = "
      UPDATE posts 
      SET post_title = '{$post_title}', 
      post_tags= '{$post_tags}', 
      post_date = now(), 
      post_image = '{$post_image}',
      post_content = '{$post_content}', 
      post_status = '{$post_status}', 
      post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', 
      post_author = case when post_author !=null then '{$post_author}' else null end, 
      post_user = case when post_user !=null then '{$post_user}' else null end 
      WHERE post_id = $the_great_post_id ";
```

Anyway you should not use PHP variables in SQL, doing so puts you are at risk for SQL injection. To avoid this you should take a look at prepared statement and binding param for your PHP db driver.

Comment: Then I added  above if(null != $_POST['post_author']) {

    $post_author = $_POST['post_author']; 
    } elseif (null != $_POST['post_user']) {

     $post_user = $_POST['post_user']; 
    } else {

null == $_POST['post_author'];
null == $_POST['post_user'];

    } but any way author or user are not been updated and deleted instead

Comment: your question is about sql error  ..  and my answer  is for this  (hope you have not more the sql error)  .... i'm not in your code   context.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
SET post_author = case when post_author !=null then '{$post_author}' 
                                               else null end,
```

there are a few problems,firstly you don't need the `SET`.  Secondly, using `else null` will set the value to null rather than leaving the field with it's original value.

In this version, it uses...

```
post_author = case when post_author is null then '{$post_author}' else post_author end,
```

which put together gives you...

```
UPDATE posts 
    SET post_title = '{$post_title}', 
        post_tags= '{$post_tags}', 
        post_date = now(), 
        post_image = '{$post_image}', 
        post_content = '{$post_content}', 
        post_status = '{$post_status}', 
        post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', 
        post_author = case when post_author is null then '{$post_author}' else post_author end, 
        post_user = case when post_user is null then '{$post_user}' else post_user end 
    WHERE post_id = $the_great_post_id
```

The other thing to point out is that you should be using prepared statements as this is insecure and can allow all sorts of problems.

Comment: actually this must also be added in the code, not in the sql if(isset($_POST['post_author'])){

$post_author = $_POST['post_author'];
}

if(isset($_POST['post_user'])){

  $post_user = $_POST['post_user'];
} now it works fine!